# need absent and present count with month name

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I need a month name with absent and present count. This is my database query:

```
SELECT sid,COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='A' THEN 1 END) AS absent_count,COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='P' THEN 1 END) AS present_count,
      MONTHNAME(attendance_date) AS `Month_Name`
      FROM attendance
      WHERE SID = '2'
      AND campus_id = 2
      GROUP BY sid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in group by `sid` - it will always be `'2'`, as per your `where` clause. Instead, since you want to count per month name, that should appear in the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   MONTHNAME(attendance_date) AS `Month_Name`, 
         COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='A' THEN 1 END) AS absent_count,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS ='P' THEN 1 END) AS present_count,
FROM     attendance
WHERE    sid = '2' AND campus_id = 2
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(attendance_date);
```